# How to add some search logic

Tags: java

Here we should add that logic to regardless of the letter, in these url of array argi, there was a certain word ... String "word" - a word that we introduce in the search.Help please.Here is code:

```
public class Search {

    private String word;
    private String str="";

            public String getWord() {
            return word;
        }

        public void setWord(String word) {
            this.word = word;
        }
        public String getStr() {
            return str;
        }

        public void setStr(String str) {
            this.str = str;
        }

        private final Pattern TITLE = Pattern.compile("\\<title\\>(.*)\\<\\/title\\>");

        public String search(String url, String someword) {

            try {
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream(),"UTF-8");
                StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
                int ch;
                while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                    input.append((char) ch);
                }
                if (Pattern.compile(someword).matcher(input).find()) {
                    Matcher title = TITLE.matcher(input);
                    if (title.find()) {
                        return title.group(1);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        public String toString() {
            String[] argi = {"http://localhost:8080/site/endipnagradi", "http://localhost:8080/site/contacts_en", "http://localhost:8080/site/news_en"};

            for (int i = 0; i < argi.length; i++) {
            String result = search(argi[i], word);
            String regex = "^[А-Яа-я]+$";


            if (result != null && word.length()>2) {

                    str += "Search phrase " + "<b>"+ word + "</b>" + " have found in " + "<a href=\"" + argi[i] + "\">" + result + "</a>"+ "<p></p>";

                     }

            if(word.length()<3 || word.matches(regex)){

               str="Word not found!";
             }

            if (word == null || word.isEmpty()) {

                str = "Enter a search word!";

              }
            }
          return null;
    }
}
```

For example, i put word "phone" but my content has just word "Phone". So anyway the search should find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your pattern with the correct option, so that it will do a case-insensitive match.
Change the code from:

```
if (Pattern.compile(someword).matcher(input).find())
```

to

```
if (Pattern.compile(someword, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(input).find())
```

For more info, look [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/case_insensitive_matching_in_java).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `equalsIgnoreCase();`. Then you can have a solution

```
 "phone".equalsIgnoreCase("Phone") ; // this will return true and found the word
```

Comment: but i have variable String word. How to add it to my code?